# Outlook VBA Macro and custom ribbon

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook, vba, outlook-add-in

I have created a couple of simple VBA macros in Outlook Developer to be able to create new emails with certains templates that are saved in Sharepoint and added these macros to a customized ribbon.

1. Is it possible to save the .oft templates in Sharepoint and have the VBA opening it instead of storing templates in the local drive?
2. Is it possible to share the Macros and customized ribbon to my colleagues?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can store .oft files in SharePoint.
2. This is a bit off topic, since this is a SharePoint forum. I'm not sure whether this possible.